# Why does names of POSIXlt return NULL?

Tags: r

If POSIXlt is a "named list of vectors" and names can "get and set the "names" attribute of a vector", why does names(POSIXlt) return null?

```
> d <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())
> class(d)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
> names(d)
NULL
```

I see unclass will return the names:

```
> unclass(d)
$sec
[1] 0

$min
[1] 0
...
```

Comment: `names(as.POSIXlt(c(a="2017-01-03")))`returns `"a"` and `names(Sys.Date())` returns `NULL`

Comment: `attr(d, "names")` will work. `names` was probably not the best name for an attribute in all fairness.

Comment: There is a `POSIXlt` method for `names`, which is why the behaviour differs when you unclass the POSIXlt object.

Comment: Thanks, these comments were all very helpful.